# WKWebView crashes after Japanese language input in Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, telerik, wkwebview

I am creating iOS app using cordova 5.2.0 (cordova-ios 3.8.0) on an iPad Air2. And I am currently trying to use the telerik-WKWebView-plugin version 0.4.0 (https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView).

### Problem

When I write Japanese in input(type=text) or textarea, WKWebView crashes.
This does not happen when inputting using English.
Any ideas what's wrong? Is there any workaround?

I have these plugins installed:

```
com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview 0.4.0 "WKWebView Polyfill"
com.shazron.cordova.plugin.keychainutil 2.0.0 "KeyChain Plugin for Cordova iOS"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-webserver 1.0.3 "CordovaWebServer"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.2.0 "Toast"
```

### crash log

```
Incident Identifier: C0BFA434-10D4-4D06-A68A-A40F3A2FE6FF
CrashReporter Key:   8efab59a8f19fbe4dc7c57c0483ef6ceba677767
Hardware Model:      iPad5,4
Process:             com.apple.WebKit.WebContent [1469]
Path:                /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Identifier:          com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Version:             8600.1.4.17.9 (8600)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-09-10 11:32:01.633 +0900
Launch Time:         2015-09-10 11:31:32.374 +0900
OS Version:          iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x00000001954fa9bc WebCore::VisibleSelection::VisibleSelection(WebCore::Range const*, WebCore::EAffinity, bool) + 40
1   WebKit                          0x000000018b3e0670 WebKit::WebPage::setCompositionAsync(WTF::String const&,     WTF::Vector<WebCore::CompositionUnderline, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>, WebKit::EditingRange const&, WebKit::EditingRange const&) + 136
2   WebKit                          0x000000018b3e0670 WebKit::WebPage::setCompositionAsync(WTF::String const&,     WTF::Vector<WebCore::CompositionUnderline, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>, WebKit::EditingRange const&, WebKit::EditingRange const&) + 136
3   WebKit                          0x000000018b3ef2cc void IPC::callMemberFunctionImpl<WebKit::WebPage, void (WebKit::WebPage::*)(WTF::String const&,     WTF::Vector<WebCore::CompositionUnderline, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>, WebKit::EditingRange const&, WebKit::EditingRange const&),     std::__1::tuple<WTF::String, WTF::Vector<WebCore::CompositionUnderline, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>, WebKit::EditingRange, WebKit::EditingRange>, 0ul,     1ul, 2ul, 3ul>(WebKit::WebPage*, void (WebKit::WebPage::*)(WTF::String const&, WTF::Vector<WebCore::CompositionUnderline, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>,     WebKit::EditingRange const&, WebKit::EditingRange const&), std::__1::tuple<WTF::String, WTF::Vector<WebCore::CompositionUnderline, 0ul,     WTF::CrashOnOverflow>, WebKit::EditingRange, WebKit::EditingRange>&&, std::index_sequence<0ul, 1ul, 2ul, 3ul>) + 80
4   WebKit                          0x000000018b3ee4d0 void IPC::handleMessage<Messages::WebPage::SetCompositionAsync, WebKit::WebPage, void     (WebKit::WebPage::*)(WTF::String const&, WTF::Vector<WebCore::CompositionUnderline, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>, WebKit::EditingRange const&,     WebKit::EditingRange const&)>(IPC::MessageDecoder&, WebKit::WebPage*, void (WebKit::WebPage::*)(WTF::String const&,     WTF::Vector<WebCore::CompositionUnderline, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>, WebKit::EditingRange const&, WebKit::EditingRange const&)) + 80
5   WebKit                          0x000000018b3ec1fc WebKit::WebPage::didReceiveWebPageMessage(IPC::Connection*, IPC::MessageDecoder&) + 11936
6   WebKit                          0x000000018b31ad28 IPC::MessageReceiverMap::dispatchMessage(IPC::Connection*, IPC::MessageDecoder&) + 116
7   WebKit                          0x000000018b428790 WebKit::WebProcess::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection*, IPC::MessageDecoder&) + 36
8   WebKit                          0x000000018b2a56d8 IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::MessageDecoder,     std::__1::default_delete<IPC::MessageDecoder> >) + 124
9   WebKit                          0x000000018b2a7684 IPC::Connection::dispatchOneMessage() + 116
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187702ab8 WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 440
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001877030f0 WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 36
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185da7f88 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185da722c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185da52dc __CFRunLoopRun + 708
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185cd0f70 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
16  Foundation                      0x0000000186c094c4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 312
17  Foundation                      0x0000000186c6380c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
18  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000198250180 _xpc_objc_main + 664
19  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000198251eec xpc_main + 196
20  com.apple.WebKit.WebContent     0x00000001000a7a7c 0x1000a4000 + 14972
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019806aa04 start + 0
```

Comment: file an issue on the plugin github page

Comment: created issue in GitHub. https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/issues/153